# Neatly separate parameteric equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have compound  parametric sum and deviation as [image]

I want MATLAB to calculate A and give back the solution as right hand side of the Eq (neat and separate).

Is there any command?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is your input and what is the expected output for the example?

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
function [a_g, b_g, c_g, d_g, A] = calcSum(a, b , c, d, g)
    a_g = a/g;
    b_g = b/g;
    c_g = c/g;
    d_g = d/g;
    A = a_g + b_g + c_g + d_g;
    fprintf('%f = %f + %f + %f + %f', A, a_g, b_g, c_g, d_g);
end
```

Which, run like `calcSum(1, 2, 3, 4, 6);` produces

```
1.666667 = 0.166667 + 0.333333 + 0.500000 + 0.666667
```